# C# library to create temporary file invisible to other users/apps as much as possible on Linux/Mac/Windows/Android/iOS

Tags: windows, linux, osx, library, c#

My multiplatform C# app needs to create a temporary file.
Since this file is potentially confidential, and needed only by my app, I would like the file to be as invisible as possible to other apps.

On Android that would probably be implemented using [internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal). On systems like Windows where there is no way to make file invisible to other processes, it would probably be implemented using Windows file attributes. On Linux it would probably be implemented using POSIX file permissions.

Requirements:

- Open source
- Abstracts the creation of a temporary file as secure as possible
- Linux/Mac/Windows/Android/iOS

Comment: Why does it need to be a file? Why can't you keep the confidential information in memory?

Comment: @svick: Because it can be several gigabytes.